# How do I calculate averages of values from comboboxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with a simple program with 3 combo box and 1 button, also 1 text box. when i click button average in text box should display the average of 3 selected numbers from combo box. i have also a behind code but it doesnt work. could someone of you help me

```
    <ComboBox Name="cb6" Margin="2,9,0,0">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="5"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="6"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="7"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="8"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="9"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="10"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Name="cb7" Margin="2,9,0,0">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="5"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="6"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="7"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="8"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="9"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="10"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Name="cb8" Margin="2,9,0,0">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="5"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="6"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="7"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="8"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="9"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="10"/>
        </ComboBox>


<TextBox Name="txtaverage" Width="100" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        <Button Name="btnaverage" Width="80" Content="Mesatarja" Click="btnmesatarja_Click" />

   behind code 
  txtaverage.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(cb6.SelectedItem)+Convert.ToDouble(cb7.SelectedItem)+ Convert.ToDouble(cbnota8.SelectedItem)/3).ToString();
```

Comment: what is the problem here ?

Comment: Can you expand any on 'it doesn't work'? Does it throw any errors? Does it do something unexpected? No text in the TextBox? Something completely different?

Comment: when i click button to get average it is displayed a message box with those information InvalidCastException was unhandled  .....                                       Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: toString inside convert ? I don't think that will work ..

Comment: i was also thinking could it work in that way;
average.text = ((cb6.selecteditem)+(cb7.selecteditem)+(cb8.selecteditem)/3)

Comment: which example ? selectedItem wont work just like that afaik..

Comment: The SelectedItem of a ComboBox is a ComboBoxItem, which is not the same thing as a string. You'll get a weird result if you ToString SelectedItem directly. You need to grab a value out of it first, hence the answer's 'cb6.Text', rather than 'cb6.SelectedItem'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple cases you can use combobox.Text

```
txtaverage.Text = ((Convert.ToDouble(cb6.Text)+Convert.ToDouble(cb7.Text)+ Convert.ToDouble(cb8.Text))/3).ToString();
```

in other cases I would recommend to get the object from selectedItem/SelectedValue and look for your value in its content.

-- further clarification for op

```
        var sum = 0.0;
        var divisor = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cb6.Text))
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(cb6.Text);
            divisor++;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cb7.Text))
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(cb7.Text);
            divisor++;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cb8.Text))
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(cb8.Text);
            divisor++;
        }

        if (divisor > 0)
        {
            txtaverage.Text = (sum/divisor).ToString();
        }
```

Comment: You may missed a pare of `()` before `/3`

Comment: sorry, did I miss something ?

Comment: The sums are off - he divided the last number by 3, rather than take an average.

Comment: oh BODMAS ! yea cant ignore that, changed ans

Comment: goobering some help with the code.

Comment: well that's not working clearly is it? you can use code in this ans and it should work, and remember.. internet is correct ( usually )

Comment: muds could also tell me, if one of combo box is null without selected numbers to dont get in process average

Comment: yes because you are not testing for nulls ..

Comment: i know that i am not testing , but for example if i dont select all combobox, just two combo box , then in textbox display just two combobox, could you help me :)

Comment: that's a different question imo

Comment: sorry for my question, the code that you gave me worked, thanks :), but i wanted to make my program better

Comment: added.. hope it helps